# jQuery positioning differences between Chrome(webkit) and Firefox

Tags: jquery, webkit, positioning

While working on a jQuery UI range slider, I was mainly debugging in chrome.  I needed to make the range have a limit so I would grab the left position of one of the handles like so:

`$el.css('left');`

Which would give me the left position as a percentage: `84%`.  However, when I tested in Firefox, it was returning the value in pixels.

Has anyone experienced this before?  Based on looking at the DOM in Firebug, Firefox does recognize percent-based left positioning but it doesn't seem to return that as a value.  Is this default behavior for Firefox?  Is this the same in IE as well?

Comment: Good question.  I was surprised recently to find css('left') returning pixels in Firefox when the property was specified as a percentage (or ems).  After all, you can always get the pixel value using position().left.  Haven't checked it out in Chrome, though.

Comment: Ya, i was suprised myself when one of the elements just shot off the screen when I thought I was basically done with that functionality.  Working on a MBP w/o VMWare or the like, so can't really test for IE right now.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but a jQuery-based workaround is to use `position` (http://api.jquery.com/position/), which returns the same value (in pixels) on every browser.

Comment: @Emmett, I was doing that, but since the `position` values are truncated (as in, no decimal values), the jQuery UI range slider handles would "jump" sometimes, making for an awkward experience.  It seems like this is just the way the implementation is until someone says otherwise.

Comment: If no solution is found here, please consider filing a bug report on the jQuery website. My first guess would have been that it returns the internally stored value, which is pixels. But as you said it would still display percentage in firebug … You may want to check the computed tab in firebug. Other than that, I’m out of ideas and can see this maybe being a bug.

Comment: A quick test here showed a pixel value as "left" in Firebug, and a percent value on Chrome Developer Tools. The same if calling getComputedStyle directly. Considering the definition of getComputedStyle() by the W3C, I am actually surprised that for Chrome a percentage value is considered a "computed" value. I expected all browsers to return a pixel value instead.

Comment: If `position` is not enough for you, I wonder how/where exactly you are *setting* the percentage values. If the browser is not returning an intact percentage value for you, maybe you'll want to store the value somewhere else so you can retrieve them?

Comment: @ehabkost - the jquery ui slider sets the values internally

Answer (score 1):

use `$el.position().left;` instead :)

Comment: That can return the same result if you've no luck. (at the moment for me)

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe that there are any known differences for positioning with jQuery as of the latest version 1.4.4.

Answer (score 0):

I have used a plugin in the past: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/dimensions

Answer (score 0):

The css () function returns the value of the specified css property as reported by the browser. As a result, it's browser specific and shouldn't be used when dealing with lengths and positioning in this way.

Comment: I agree, the css() function lets you manipulate or read css properties and those are (sadly) interpreted differently per browser. Use the position() function if you want browser independent figures and results.

Answer (score 0):

I worked around this issue by accessing DOM directly, like this:

`$el.get(0).style.left`

it returns the % value for FF, Chrome, Safari and IE9. (Didn't test it on Opera, though)